# i am trying to get the text in a Button from another Activity

Tags: android

I have a main activity  and in this activity i have a button in this button i have a Text i went to get the text from another activity,what i should do to make that happen the simple way to getText() dos't work.

thanks for helping

Comment: Post some code, so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add params to your intent like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_BUTTONTEXT, yourButtonText);
 context.startActivityForResult(intent, SecondActivity.SECONDACTIVITY_REQUEST);
```

And from the second activity, get the param like this:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      String yourButtonText = extras.getString(EXTRA_BUTTONTEXT);
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Intent. Why do you need the text of the button in another activity?

Comment: in my main activity when i press the button i move to a list,when i choose i get back to the main activity this text is what i need in my other activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preference for Storage of data and use that data any where you want.

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood... Anyway, it's more less like firefox1986 explained. You must start activity for result, as you pass a value to another activity. If you want to change the label of the button sometime later or just have a beautiful code, then write `TextView buttonLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.button1);` and then pass `buttonLabel` to Extras.